# how to activate proguard in my project?

Tags: android, proguard

I want to prevent my application from being reverse engineered and decompiled by someone else. How do I activate proguard in my project to assist me in achieving this?

```
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
```

Should I be writing this into my application?

Comment: this is need to write or only you say proguard.config=proguard.cfg is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Progaurd](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) obfuscates the code and makes it tough to reverse engineer. The mapping files generated by proguard needs to be preserved, in case you may want to re-engineer the code. I would say, it is pretty much handy to use it for any market build.

**EDIT**

progaurd.cfg would have been automatically created when you are creating an Android project via eclipse.

You may now want to enable progaurd for your project. There may be a file say default.properties which includes the target of your application. You may want to add the below line

```
proguard.config = proguard.cfg
```

to enable progaurd for your application. You are now all set for progaurd enabled application. If progaurd is successfully configured, on export of your apk you may see a folder progaurd generated with a list of files in it. (Refer Enabling Progaurd in the link provided). Hope it helps

Comment: can you explain how I do it? I dont understand that link

Comment: really thanks but I am not clearly understand pls help.Firstly you say below line , where I write that line? and what do ı then?

Comment: Add proguard.config=proguard.cfg to default.properties (project.properties). That should enable progaurd in your project.

Comment: thanks so when ı do this, another person dont decompile my project

Comment: It is code obfuscation, you can still decompile it but reading the decompiled code is near impossible, until and unless he has the mapping files generated by progaurd.

Comment: The progaurd.cfg needs to have the stuff like what you have mentioned in the code, apart from that you may want to associate the progaurd to your project. proguard.config=proguard.cfg enables progaurd and it runs the configurations mentioned in progaurd.cfg during export of apk. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

To simply activate enable in your project:

1. Create a file called `<project_root>/proguard.cfg` in your project.
2. In your `<project_root>/project.properties`, add `proguard.config=proguard.cfg`.

Then you would need to define your Proguard configurations for your project in the proguard.cfg file. You can read about the various proguard options that go into this file from the [Proguard website](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html). You can read more on using Proguard with Android in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

Comment: thanks for answering. What do you mean 1.Create a file called <project_root>/proguard.cfg in your project ? what is this <project_root>

Comment: The root folder for your project where all the other directories, including src and res reside.

Comment: I am create file <project_root>/proguard.cfg ? it already in there.?

Comment: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html look that link in there look-- A complete Android application  -- and Ama I copy paste in there codes to my proguard.cfg